# Show images depending slider value with jQuery

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm using this slider : https://codepen.io/dubrod/pen/osDmg.

I would like to insert an image depending the slider value.

For example, if the slider value is `10` I would like to show `10` images.

So my code is the following:

```
$('.show-rooms').empty();
for (var i=1; i<=slider_value; i++) {
    $('.show-rooms').prepend('<img src="https://wheelspinmodels.co.uk/images/messenger-icon-grey20.gif" />');
}
```

The problem is when the div is refresh, it flashes.

How can I change this to make it more user friendly ?

My test is here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mjLoRv

Thanks.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: I didn't see any flash, anyway if you want to show same image each time, you can preload the image.